# ¿Cuál es el origen y significado de la expresión "Tampoco el congrio es mal ave"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

El [**congrio**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AJqFYzd) es

> 1. m. Pez teleósteo, del suborden de los fisóstomos, que alcanza de uno a dos metros de largo, con el cuerpo gris oscuro, casi cilíndrico, bordes negros en las aletas dorsal y anal, y carne blanca y comestible.

por lo que la expresión "**tampoco el congrio es mal ave**" no parece tener mucho sentido, y no aparece recogido en el Diccionario de la Lengua o en el [refranero de CVC](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Busqueda.aspx)

Sin embargo es una expresión que sí se utiliza, por ejemplo [aquí](http://blogs.periodistadigital.com/cajondesastre.php/2009/04/11/p227663), [aquí](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=2341363), [aquí](http://carolinadeandres.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/tampoco-el-congrio-es-mal-ave.html) y [aquí](http://malas-notas.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/perogrulladas-en-el-refranero.html), sin que quede claro su origen o significado.

¿Cuál es, entonces, el origen y significado de "**Tampoco el congrio es mal ave**"?

Comment: Ninguna entrada ni en el CORDE ni en el CREA. Aunque el último enlace de los que propones dice que no tiene significado, que es una simple ocurrencia humorística.

Answer (score 1):

Después de mucho buscar, he conseguido encontrar una referencia a la expresión. Se encuentra en la página 3 de la [edición del 6 de enero de 1921 de El Heraldo de Madrid](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000771362&page=3&search=congrio%20mal%20ave&lang=es). En esta página hay un artículo titulado "Curiosidades - Talegas entre blasones", firmado por el pseudónimo "Rigel", que narra la cena de un millonario en un restaurante, de la siguiente forma:

> Pero cada uno es como el diablo le ha hecho, y aun peor, y un deslenguado me contó no ha mucho que en cierto banquete, al que asistía uno de estos hombres bárbaramente enriquecidos, sirvieron un plato de faisán sabrosamente condimentado, del cual se comió una buena ración el hombre de los muchos millones.
>       Gran parecido encontraba el Creso del nuevo cuño la sazonada carne a la del pollo; pero ni por semejas podía confundirla con ella, y como pensaba regalarse en lo sucesivo con análoga pitanza, y no sabía su nombre, se atrevió a preguntárselo al comensal que estaba a su lado derecho:
>       —Dígame usted, y perdone: ¿cómo se llama esto que comemos?
>       —Ave—dijo, mostrando extrañeza, el preguntado.
>       Y aquí entra lo único censurable que podemos advertir en la conducta de crematístico insigne. El prurito de mostrarse enterado de todo apareció a sus ojos con gesto tentador y al punto en que comenzaba a comer del siguiente plato, que él conocía muy bien por ser de congrio guisado, dijo el ricachón, inclinándose al oído de su vecino de la izquierda:
>       —¡Tampoco es mal ave el congrio!

Así pues, parece que el artículo dejó huella en el saber popular. Hay algunos relatos, como el que enlazas, que afirman que el autor de la frase es Eduardo Dato. Ignoro si este artículo es original, si es un plagio, si está inventado o si está basado en hechos reales. El caso es que Eduardo Dato murió a los dos meses de escribirse ese artículo, y tu enlace dice que la anécdota sucedió "unos pocos días antes". Puede que Eduardo Dato, que vivía en Madrid por entonces, hubiera leído recientemente el artículo mencionado antes de aquella cena homenaje. O puede que fuera al revés, que el artículo estuviera basado en la anécdota de Eduardo Dato. Es difícil saberlo.

Tomando el artículo por auténtico, la expresión no sería más que una forma de ponerse en evidencia el que habla, revelando que en realidad no conoce el tema del que trata. En todo caso, hoy en día parece que el uso que se le da es más parecido a la anécdota de don Eduardo: se usa para expresar que una alternativa no está nada mal en comparación con la original (o incluso en general). Ejemplo:

> Jean Luc Godard había estado casado con Ana Karina, que tampoco es mal ave el congrio... ([enlace](https://elventalledecedros.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/anne-wiazemsky/))